# Unable to call webmethod in autocomplete textbox

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete, ajaxcontroltoolkit, webmethod

aspx page code:

```
<ajax:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1"  runat="server">
 <Services >
  <ajax:ServiceReference Path="MyService.asmx" />
 </Services>
</ajax:ScriptManager>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtMaterialNo"  
             Width="100%" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>


       <cc1:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" CompletionInterval="20"
        MinimumPrefixLength="1" ServiceMethod="GetMaterialId"
         ServicePath="MyService.asmx" TargetControlID="txtMaterialNo"> </cc1:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

MyService.asmx

```
    [ScriptService]
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
public class MyService : System.Web.Services.WebService
 public MyService()
    {

        //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
        //InitializeComponent(); 
    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public string[] GetMaterialId(string prefixMaterial)
    {
...... code
.... return
    }
  }
```

But when I am typing into the textbox no suggestion are coming, when I am placing the breakpoint at GetMaterialId I can see that it is not coming to this function but it is calling MyService on textchange.

How to fix this? Why it is calling the constructor but not the webmethod?

Comment: What _is_ it doing? Try watching the network traffic with [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).

Comment: @John Saunders I am running it on my local machine.

Comment: @Chris: why is this a problem?

Comment: @John Saunders I have no idea. I can see "yellow" breakpoint at  public MyService() function but not at the one which I am calling i.e. GetMaterialId. Any suggestion?

Comment: @Chris: I mean why is it a problem that you're running on your local machine?

Comment: @John Saunders  any idea how can I do it ?

Comment: @Chris: I don't know - you didn't answer my question. Why can't you use Fiddler on your local machine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the [ScriptMethodAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.services.scriptmethodattribute.aspx) like so:

```
    [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string[] GetMaterialId(string prefixMaterial)
    {
        ...... code
        .... return
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Myabe your project is not setup as an AJAX.NET site; try [Adding ASP.NET AJAX to an Existing ASP.NET Application](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/ajax/EnableAjax.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Your method signature is wrong, I think.  Its supposed to be:

```
List<string> GetMaterialId(string prefixMaterial, int count)
```

where count is the number of items to return.

Comment: I tried the same but the complier is not at all coming to this function.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" in your source page:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="cc1" %>
```